# Convert curl command to HTTParty Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, curl, httparty

I'm currently trying to send a get request in HTTParty that logs in and gets some API data.  I've successfully done this via curl by doing:

```
curl -v --user USERNAMEHERE:PassWordHere http://app.ionitnetworks.com/ionit-app/api/rest/v1/devices
```

This outputs in my console:

```
➜  HeatWatch git:(kunzig_new_heatwatch) ✗ curl -v --user (userOmitted):(password_omitted) http://app.ionitnetworks.com/ionit-app/api/rest/v1/devices
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.92.23.58...
* Connected to app.ionitnetworks.com (23.92.23.58) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'userOmitted'
> GET /ionit-app/api/rest/v1/devices HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic ZG91Z0dofW301320Y2AsayZlLmNvbTpkb3VnMTIz
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: app.ionitnetworks.com
> Accept: */*
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff to get this to work in httparty but nothing has worked such as:

```
@response = HTTParty.post("https://app.ionitnetworks.com/ionit-app/api/rest/v1/devices.json", :headers =>{ "Authorization" =>"Token token=\"AccountsTokenOmitted\"" })
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found that for me `-u USERNAME:PASSWORD` in curl is for the most part equivalent to `basic_auth` in HTTParty. I also like setting my options in a separate variable to make it a little easier to read/edit/adjust and then pass that variable to the call.

```
options = {
  basic_auth: { username: USERNAME, password: PASSWORD }
}

HTTParty.post(<URL>, options)
```